# Displaying local swf files with FileReader

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the file picker functionality to chose an SWF file from my desktop and display it in embed or object tags. I can get the picker to open no problem but when choosing an SWF file it falls over and simply wont display it. I have tried multiple different sources of code. Loading things like PNG and JPG is fine they display no problem, but no luck with SWF files.

One of the code segments I am trying to get to work is as follows:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('OBJECT');
          span.innerHTML = ['src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          //document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

To note it doesnt have to be this particular block of code, any ideas or alternatives are most welcome. This is modified from the version that did work with other image types like PNG and JPG.

Cheers

Comment: Erm, try using `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldnt get a solution that allows me to select from anywhere, I do have one that lets me chose from the same folder location. It will do for now.
This is as follows:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li>', escape(f.name),                 
                  '</li>');
    }

    var x = document.createElement("EMBED");
    x.setAttribute("src", output[1]);
    document.body.appendChild(x);

  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

But again it only works if the file and SWFs are in the same location.